# Uploadify Error in FireFox using CodeIgniter MVC

Tags: codeigniter, uploadify

I spent whole day on finding solution but could not.I have simplified my code to find issue but could not found.
The same code working in Chrome but not in FireFox.

**ERROR** (some time getting one error some time other)

1. IO error
2. HTTP error 303

Here is my code

```
$('#file_upload').uploadify({
        'swf'      : '<?php echo base_url();?>uploadifyit/uploadify.swf',
        'uploader' : '<?php echo site_url()?>/rentals/rental_imageUpload',
        'onError' : function(event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj) { alert(errorObj.type + ' ' + errorObj.info ); }
        // Your options here
    });
```

I have included

```
jquery.uploadify.min.js
```

I downloaded the latest UPLOADIFY from server and followed these [steps](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/uploadify/implementing-uploadify/)

Here is my controller function

```
public function rental_imageUpload(){
    echo 1;
}
```

Comment: Can you post exactly the errors you receive and when you get them?

Comment: If you read my question,I have mentioned that I am getting IO error,after processing